# Number Runner Program

Tags: java

So I have to write a program where if you have a number, the program can tell if it is odd/even and perfect(meaning the sum of the factors equal the number itself). So far I have the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumberRunner2 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] numbers = new int[]{3, 21, 532, 1111, 199, 291, 19};
 {
    int x;
     System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even ");
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      x = in.nextInt();

    if ( x % 2 == 0 )
      System.out.println("Even.");
      else
     System.out.println("Odd");
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
public class Number2
{
  private Integer number;
   public Number2()
{
}
  public Number2(int num)
{

}
  public void setNumber(int num)
{

}
  public int getNumber()
{
    return 0;
}
public boolean isOdd()
{    
    return false;
}
  public boolean isPerfect()
{

    int total=0;
    return (number==total);
}
public String toString()
{

    return "";
}    
}
```

The thing is, both the programs have to be together, but I don't know how. Also, I don't know how to put a perfect number function into my code.

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html), your Number class isn't even being used, and none of the methods do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

In [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (or OOP) you're representing real-life objects, information or concepts - as objects. This is helpful partially because many objects can have the same properties.

In your exercise you're building a number-representing class `Num` which is supposed to evaluate properties of that number.

To actually construct such number in your code you can use the call to the class's constructor:

```
// this can be a call in your main function, or anywhere in fact!
Number two = new Number(2); // this represents the number "2"
```

later on, you use methods from the class of that objects, to give out properties of that object:

```
System.out.println("Is two odd? " + two.isOdd());
```

In order to do those things you write two classes. One is called the main class, which drives the program (constructs objects, performs prints to the user and more...) and another is a more passive class, the number class, which represents a number (and has methods that operate on that number).

Putting everything together:

the main class will look something like this (only longer):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Num two = new Num(2);
        System.out.println("Is two odd? " + two.isOdd());

        // and scanner...
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Num x = new Num(in.nextInt());

        // add more methods and call them on x
    }
}
```

And the number class will look something like this (again, longer):

```
public class Num {

    private int number;
    public Num(int num) {
        // save number in object's state.
        this.number = num;
    }

    public boolean isOdd() {
        // print if the number is odd or not
        return this.number % 2 != 0;
    }

}
```

Another great programming skill is searching:

When you're in trouble, Google has all answers. Think about the terms that uniquely identify your problem and use them in your search (for example: "How do I use a while loop in java?" is probably the same as searching "while loop java")

You can also start by using Oracle's tutorials on [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)